# For complex number $z_1$ and $z_2$ determine angle $z_1 O z_2$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $w=\frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{2}$ and $P=\{w^n:n=1,2,3,.... \}$ Further $H_1=\{z \in C: Re(z)>\frac{1}{2} \}$ and $H_2=\{z \in C: Re(z)<-\frac{1}{2} \}$, where $C$ is the set of all complex numbers. If $z_1\in P \cap H_1 $ and $z_2\in P \cap H_2$ and $O$ represents the origin, then angle $z_1 O z_2$=

$(A)$ $\frac{\pi}{2}$

$(B)$ $\frac{\pi}{6}$

$(C)$ $\frac{2\pi}{3}$

$(D)$ $\frac{5\pi}{6}$

More than one option may be correct.

I know we can write $w=\cos \frac{\pi}{6}+ i \sin \frac{\pi}{6}$

Can we $w^1$ as $z_1$ [As $Re(z)>\frac{1}{2}$] and $w^5$ and $w^6$ as $z_2$  and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Let's go in increasing order of angles:

$\frac \pi 6 \rightarrow$ The minimum angular distance between any elements in $P$ is $\frac \pi 6$ and if you visualize all of the powers of $w$ on the complex plane, you'll see that there's no way two elements of $P$ can be on different sides of the imaginary number line if they are adjacent powers, so elements in $P \cap H_1$ and $P \cap H_2$ have a distance of more than $\frac \pi 6$. Thus, $\frac \pi 6$ is not one of the answers.

$\frac \pi 2 \rightarrow$ We can choose $z_1=w^2$ and $z_2=w^5$ to get an angle of $\frac{3\pi}6=\frac \pi 2$. However, $w^2$ has a real part of $\frac 1 2$, and if you go through the powers of $w$ again, you'll see the closest we can get to a solution is where either $z_1$ or $z_2$ has a real part of $\frac 1 2$, so there's no solution here.

$\frac {2\pi} 2 \rightarrow$ We can choose $z_1=w$ and $z_2=w^5$ to get an angle of $\frac{4\pi}6=\frac {2\pi} 3$.

$\frac {5\pi} 6 \rightarrow$ We can choose $z_1=w$ and $z_2=w^6$ to get an angle of $\frac{5\pi}6$.

Furthermore, if we choose $z_1=w^{12}$ and $z_2=w^6$, we get an angle of $pi$. There are more possibilities if we allow reflex angles.